# jQuery.validate() firing on button clicks (I want only on submit)

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

The end of my form is like:

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class=" btn btn-primary" >    
<a href="register.php" ><button class="btn btn-primary" >Register</button></a>    
<a href="/"><button class="btn btn-primary" >Cancel</button></a>
</form>
```

then:

```
jQuery("form#login").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("#loading").modal();
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

When you click the login button, the form validates, as expected.  However, the form is also validating on click of either of the two buttons, in the form.  These other two buttons are just links, I need them *in* the form, so that I can display them all in a row.

Probly, it's to do with validate() firing on :submit, which is any button, in the form.  How can I tell it only validate on an actual click of the submit button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give the buttons a type='button'

e.g.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" >Cancel</button>
```

This is because, if you don't set it, some browsers default it to type='submit'.